# number of variables based on users input?

Tags: python

I have to ask for an input of how many cats the user has then print a table based on the information alongside others such as their colour and age. how do I do this without making multiple variables such as cat1, cat2, cat3. It should need to work for whatever amount of cats the user inputs.

Comment: this is the exact use case of an array

Comment: Please search a little more for the question. There are a lot of samples. Good luck.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the challenge here is not storing a list of cat names but associated data alongside them.

For each cat you would like to store it's colour, age, etc and then be able to extract them all.

Some other users have suggested using 'arrays' which are called 'lists' in python so you can google them. However, it is a little more complex than just storing a list of strings if you want to associate the data.

Luckily, python allows us to store lists as entries in other lists. So instead of having a single list storing all the cats names as strings and then another list with all the colours, we can store a list where each entry is a list containing all the details we need about the cat. Which would be *one* way of doing it.

Kinda like this:

( (Cat1, Colour1, Age1) , (Cat2, Colour2, Age2) , ... )

Which can be as long or short as you need. I'll let you find out how you would go about declaring all that pythonicaly.

Lists are a mutable data type in python, allowing you to change data within them depending on how you are getting data from the user. You can add extra entries to the end using the 'append' method.

You should also have a look at 'dicts' or dictionaries. Which would allow you to search through the dictionary by the name of the specific cat. However, these are an immutable data type in python (they cannot be changed once created), so may be unsuitable depending on how you go about getting user input.